# finding power spectrum of signal using two approaches

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to find power spectrum of the signal. The length of the signal is `100000`, sample frequency is `1000Hz`,and the number of points is `100000`. I found the power spectrum using two approaches. The first one is by taking all the length as one part and found power spectrum for it while the second approach is by dividing the signal into `100*1000`and find spectrum for each row then get the mean for all rows. My problem is that I must get the same answer in both approaches but I got different answers. I do not know what is the error in my code.

```
N=100000;
SF=1000;      
a=0.1;
b=0.3; 
amplitude1=1;
amplitude2=0.5;
t=0:1/SF:100;
f1=SF*a;
f2=SF*b;
A=amplitude1*sin(2*pi*f1*t)+amplitude2*sin(2*pi*f2*t);
Y=2*randn(1,length(A))+A;
bin=[0 :N/2];
fax_Hz=(bin*SF)/N;
FFT=fft(Y);
spectra=2/(SF*length(Y))*(FFT.*conj(FFT));
plot(fax_Hz,spectra(1,1:50001));
D=reshape(Y(1,1:100000),[100,1000]);
M=length(D(1,:));
for i=1:100
    FFT_1(i,:)=fft(D(i,:));
    S(i,:)=(2/(SF*M))*(FFT_1(i,:).*conj(FFT_1(i,:)));
end
S_f=mean(S);
figure
plot (S_f);
```

I just update the code. I do not know but when I added noise to signal the two plots looks shifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is with `reshape` you are working with each row being a separate sequence. Reshape however fills the first column before moving to the second one.

You can use the following instead.

```
D=reshape(A(1,1:100000),[1000,100]).';
```

Normalization is another problem. You can either use `ifft` instead of `fft` as it is normalized by default (not sure why). Or alternatively keep your normalization and instead of using `mean` you should can use `sum`, maybe that is due to a mistake you might have made. There still seems to be a small discrepancy in the amplitudes, not sure where that is coming from.

At the end to plot use the following:

```
bin=[0 :N];
fax_Hz=(bin*SF)/N;
FFT=ifft(A);
spectra=FFT.*conj(FFT);
plot(fax_Hz,spectra); hold on
D=reshape(A(1,1:100000),[1000,100]).';
M=length(D(1,:));
for i=1:100
    FFT_1(i,:)=ifft(D(i,:));
    S(i,:)=FFT_1(i,:).*conj(FFT_1(i,:));
end
S_f=mean(S);
plot(fax_Hz(1:100:end-1), S_f);
```

*Note: the `fax_Hz(1:100:end-1)` is a hacky way of getting the length of the vectors to be the same.*

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please, I do not know but when I added noise to the signal, the two plots looks shifted. I just update the code to see that.

Comment: I can not reproduce that problem. From your code remove everything from the `bin` below and replace it the code that I posted. (obviously rename `A` to `Y`)